# How to print a specific number of objects of an array on each line

Tags: php

http://cps276.net/zgambrell/08/index.php

The program takes user input for Number of Cases, Number of packs per case, number of cards per pack, and then the frequency number of uncommon, rare , and legendary cards in the case. It is similar to the "fizzbuzz" test.

"The Client" wants each pack of cards outputted onto its own separate line. This is the current problem I am having.

I am still new to working with php and object oriented programming.

Here is all my code:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    Total Number of Cases:
    <input type="text" name="totNumCases" value="" /><br/>
    Number of Packs in Each Case:
    <input type="text" name="packsInEachCase" value="" /><br/>
    Base Number of Cards in Each Pack:
    <input type="text" name="baseNumCards" value="" /><br/>
    Frequency of "Uncommon" Cards:
    <input type="text" name="freqUncommon" value="" /><br/>
    Frequency of "Rare" Cards:
    <input type="text" name="freqRare" value="" /><br/>
    Frequency of "Legendary" Cards:
    <input type="text" name="freqLegendary" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="Submit" /><br/>
    <hr />

</form>


<?php

$cardsPerPack = $_POST['baseNumCards'];
$packsPerCase = $_POST['packsInEachCase'];

class CommonCards{

    private $card;

    public function __construct($card){
        $this->card = 'COM';
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->card.' ';
    }

    public function process(CardCounter $f){
        $result = $f->increment();
        if($result){
            $this->card = $result;
        }
    }
}

class CardCounter {
    private $uncommonCount = 0;
    private $rareCount = 0;
    private$legendaryCount = 0;

    public function increment(){
        $this->uncommonCount++;
        $this->rareCount++;
        $this->legendaryCount++;
        $out = '';
        if($this->uncommonCount == $_POST['freqUncommon']){
            $this->uncommonCount = 0;
            $out.='UNC';
        }
        if($this->rareCount == $_POST['freqRare']){
            $this->rareCount = 0;
            $out.='RAR';
        }
        if($this->legendaryCount == $_POST['freqLegendary']){
            $this->legendaryCount = 0;
            $out.='LEG';
        }

        return $out;
    }

}

$arr = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= ($cardsPerPack * $packsPerCase); $i++){
    $arr[] = new CommonCards($i);//getting all cards, setting them all equal to COM. "common cards"
}
$f = new CardCounter();

foreach($arr as $commonCards){
    $commonCards->process($f);//doing the 'fizzbuzz' process
    echo $commonCards;// printing out the total number of cards.
}
```

I have been trying to play around with using $cardsPerPack with help with this. If i could get it set to were it is only printing that number per each line it would work perfectly fine.

Otherwise I have made attempts using the % on the cardsPerPack.

Mostly I have been focusing my attempts here :

```
foreach($arr as $commonCards){
    $commonCards->process($f);//doing the 'fizzbuzz' process
    echo $commonCards;// printing out the total number of cards.
}
```

and here:

```
public function process(CardCounter $f){
        $result = $f->increment();
        if($result){
            $this->card = $result;
        }
    }
```

but all attempts have failed pretty badly.

ANY help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you just use nested while statements? The outer while loops over the packs and the inner one over the cards in each pack.

Comment: I havent been able to get anything to work with working with while loops.

I have it to this point: 
$arr = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= ($cardsPerPack * $packsPerCase); $i++){
    $arr[] = new CommonCards($i);//getting all cards, setting them all equal to COM. "common cards"
}
$f = new CardCounter();

foreach($arr as $commonCards){
    $commonCards->process($f);//doing the 'fizzbuzz' process
    
    for($j = 1; $j <= $cardsPerPack; $j++){
    echo $commonCards;// printing out the total number of cards.
}
echo "<br/>";
}

The only issue know is it is printing 10 lines of 5 cards.

Comment: I have a good idea why it is printing 10 lines of 5 cards but everything I try with the loops is printing out way more cards than are really needed. Thats because im looping through were I am getting and printing the cards. Any idea how I can fix this problem?

Comment: So your array is a list of card names, and you want to loop through it, printing 5 cards and then a line break, then printing another 5 and then another line break, until you reach the end of the array? Is that what you're trying to do?